# sed command to remove invalid characters when import CSV file into Sqlite3 Database

Tags: php, sqlite, shell, import-from-csv

I have CSV file which is having more than 100K records (File size is 50mb).
When I am importing data from CSV to Sqlite3 Database getting errors saying "expected 43 columns of data but found 78".

The reason I found was, CSV file has some invalid characters. (Refer Screenshot)

Please help me to remove invalid characters from CSV file using "Linux Sed Command"

https://prnt.sc/odr7hb

I need to modify this command with sed command to remove invalid characters.

```
sqlite3 /path_to_db/date_sqlite.db 
"<<EOS" 
.separator '|' 
.import /path_to_data_file/data_log_filr tbl_sqlite_data EOS
```

[Null Byte = These are the characters I need to remove](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JlYAZ.jpg)

Comment: I just applied code-format (4 leading spaces) to your code but it still doesn't look quite right.  So that people can help, please make the code shown match the code that you actually use.

Comment: can you post the characters that you want to remove

Comment: can you open the csv correctly using a spreadsheet program?

Comment: @yoga characters are NULL bytes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove Null Byte in a Text file

```
sed 's/\x0//g' PATH TO INPUT FILE > PATH TO OUTPUT FILE
```

To Use in PHP Exec

```
 $regx = 's/\x0//g';  

 $command = sprintf(" sed '%s' $pathToInput > $pathToOutput   ", $regx );

 exec($command)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: After removing null bytes and import data into sqlite database, it took longer time than I expected. Because of file size 40/50 Mb.

Ref: 
https://medium.com/@JasonWyatt/squeezing-performance-from-sqlite-indexes-indexes-c4e175f3c346
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1711631/improve-insert-per-second-performance-of-sqlite?rq=1

  Conclusion : 

To Improve performance of Sqlite bulk data insert/update/delete, Drop table indexing when you do sqlite operations and once the operation is done recreate table Indexing this will drastically improve performance. 

Hope this will help someone

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your input file is **not** Unicode, and so you really want to remove all NUL bytes, you can do this on the shell with

```
tr -d \\000 <input.csv >output.csv
```

Comment: You can run any shell command you like.... Just be careful with the number of `\`  characters.